# Recurrence differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have the following differential equation,

$\frac{d}{dt}c_k(t) = \frac{\beta}{2} (c_{k-1}(t)-c_{k+1}(t))$

with the initial coefficient $c_k(t=0)= f(k)$

I know that,

$\frac{d}{dt}J_n(t) = \frac{1}{2} (J_{n-1}(t)-J_{n+1}(t))$

where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. However I don't know how to take care of the additional factor $\beta$ to get a solution.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you rescale $t=t^*/\beta$?

Comment: @MrYouMath it doesn't work because you end up with d/dt*(c_n(t*/β))=1/2(c_{n−1}(t*/β)−c_{n+1}(t*/β)) solution to which isn't a Bessel function. With t multiplied by  β, the Bessel solution is, d/dt*(J_n(t*/β))=1/(2β)(J_{n−1}(t*/β)−J_{n+1}(t*/β)), whereas in my new equation I am missing β.